# SSD keeps disappearing

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, ext4, ssd, dmesg

I have an SSD connected to my Raspberry Pi 3B+ using the Element14 Pi Desktop kit.  The drive is recognized as `/dev/sda` and correctly mounted from `/etc/fstab` at boot, but then will disappear after running for a while.

I started to suspect insufficient power (despite Element14's assertion that a 2.5A power supply was sufficient to power the rpi+SSD), so I bought a new power supply that provided up to 3.5A (I have yet to confirm that with my Kill-a-Watt).  I rebooted the pi and and drive mounted correctly as usual, but after about 10 hours, `dmesg` showed:

```
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=0x00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 0c e0 00 00 00 f0 00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 843776
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=0x00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 0c e0 f0 00 00 10 00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 844016
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 105121792
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 13139968, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 843776
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 105121792
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 13139968, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 50333960
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572963: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572961: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572956: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572967: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572960: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572955: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572951: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572950: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572965: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572952: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 15761408, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 15761408, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
```

After this, the drive no longer even appears in `lsblk`.  What is causing the drive to disappear?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the USB adapter.  USB resets and disconnects.

Comment: Thnx, any suggestions on what to try or what I can do about it?